# В сокет отправляется не полная строка

Tags: java, python, строки, сокет

Есть клиент на `java`, который отправляет длинный `json` на сервер, который написан на `python`. Если длина `json`'а не очень большая, то все нормально отправляется. Если же строка большая, то доходит не вся. Обрывается где-то на 1500 символах (не точно).

Клиент:

```
    private static void connect(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
        long sessionId = new Random().nextLong();
        queue.add(sessionId);
        while (!(queue.size() <= 0 || queue.get(0).equals(sessionId)))
            try { Thread.sleep(200); } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }

        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
    }

    static String sendJsonForResult(String json) throws IOException {
        return sendJsonForResult(json, TIMEOUT);
    }

    static String sendJsonForResult(String json, int timeout) throws IOException {
        try {
            connect(ip, port);
            if (socket == null) throw new IOException("Socket is null");
            socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dos.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            dos.flush();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String response = in.readLine();
            if (response == null || response.equals(""))
                throw new IOException(String.format("Incorrect response (%s)", response));
            Log.d("CLIENT", "Answer:\n\t" + response);
            return response;
        } finally {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    private static void disconnect() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) { }
        if (queue.size() > 0) queue.remove(0);
    }
```

Сервер:

```
try:
    tcp_socket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print('[SERVER] ERROR: ' + str(e))

tcp_socket.listen(10)

while true:
    conn, addr = tpc_socket.accept()
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1048576)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        if data != '':
            print('[SERVER] Received data from ' + addr[0] + ':\n\t' + data)
```

Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: По определению, сокет не обязан передавать всё сообщение за один раз. При передаче сообщения, нужно смотреть, сколько байт отправлено, и не отправленые - отправлять повторно. Аналогично - при приёме нужно вычислить сколько байт принято или есть ли признак "конец сообщения". Если байт не хватает - то нужно дочитывать сообщение.

Comment: Если вы хотите получать "не рваное" сообщение - откажитесь от сокета, используйте протоколы верхнего уровня через готовые библиотеки (например http). Если используете сокет - делайте как описано выше.

Comment: Нужно вызывать `conn.recv(1048576)` в цикле пока не получите все данные, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/socket__tcp__examples/send_recv_complex_object/server.py#L26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Спасибо @nick_n_a и @gil9red за наводку.
Сначала в питоне я сделал следующее, как в комментариях и рекомендовали:

```
while true:
    conn, addr = tpc_socket.accept()
    try:
        databytes = bytesarray()
        while True:
             databuff = conn.recv(4096)
             if not databytes:
                 break
             databytes += databuff
        data = databytes.decode('utf-8')
        if data != '':
            print('[SERVER] Received data from ' + addr[0] + ':\n\t' + data)
```

Но появилась следующая проблема - запрос не отправлялся, пока сокет на клиенте не закроется. Я пытался закрыть `OutputStream`, но закрывался и сокет вместе с ним, а мне надо было еще и прочитать ответ.

Решение оказалось следующим: вместо `OutPutStream.close()` использовать `Socket.shutdownOutput()`.

Вот код клиента:

```
private static void connect(String ip, int port) throws IOException {
    long sessionId = new Random().nextLong();
    queue.add(sessionId);
    while (!(queue.size() <= 0 || queue.get(0).equals(sessionId)))
        try { Thread.sleep(200); } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }

    socket = new Socket(ip, port);
}

static String sendJsonForResult(String json) throws IOException {
    return sendJsonForResult(json, TIMEOUT);
}

static String sendJsonForResult(String json, int timeout) throws IOException {
    try {
        connect(ip, port);
        if (socket == null) throw new IOException("Socket is null");
        socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        dos.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        dos.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        String response = in.readLine();
        if (response == null || response.equals(""))
            throw new IOException(String.format("Incorrect response (%s)", response));
        Log.d("CLIENT", "Answer:\n\t" + response);
        return response;
    } finally {
        disconnect();
    }
}

private static void disconnect() {
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
    if (queue.size() > 0) queue.remove(0);
}
```